# Please accept this intimation

Tags: phrases, formality

What does the phrase "accept this intimation" mean in the context of a funeral notice?

Is it appropriate to use when announcing the consecration ([Unveiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bereavement_in_Judaism#Matzevah_.28Unveiling_of_the_tombstone.29) in the Jewish ritual) of a tombstone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that [genealogists](http://www.rootschat.com/forum/index.php/topic,444401/prev_next,next.html) are familiar with the phrase:

> "Friends please accept this the only intimation" meant "we are not
>   going to be sending out cards announcing the death & funeral
>   arrangements to you all". (Such cards had been the custom, but were
>   gradually replaced by newspaper announcements.)

It follows that the phrase is only appropriate if the prevailing practice is to send out individual notifications of the sad occasion [*not* the case in my community for either death or [unveiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bereavement_in_Judaism#Matzevah_.28Unveiling_of_the_tombstone.29)].

Answer (score 0):

The word *intimate* has a long-standing and accepted meaning as a verb:

Oxford Dictionaries Online, [*intimate* (2)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intimate--2):

> verb, [with object], state or make known:
>
> *Mr Hutchison has intimated his decision to retire.*

I would say that there is nothing wrong with using *accept this intimation* when announcing the consecration of a tombstone. I don't believe the phrase has any special meaning beyond that which can be inferred from the meaning of *intimate*.